# Find a word that appears several times in the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
<p>TEST TEST</p>
<p>TEST</p>
</div>
```

I would like to find and highlight all of the occurrences of the word TEST on one button click.

I'm currently using a JS function to find and bold which is a mini-plugin:

```
function findAndBold(searchText, replacement, searchNode) {
    if (!searchText) {
        // Throw error here if you want...
        return;
    }

    var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ? new RegExp(searchText, 'i') : searchText;
    var childNodes = (searchNode || document.getElementById("mainContent")).childNodes;
    var cnLength = childNodes.length;


    while (cnLength--) {

        var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength];

        if (currentNode.nodeType === 1) {
            arguments.callee(searchText, replacement, currentNode);
        }

        if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data)) {
            continue;
        }

        var parent = currentNode.parentNode;

        var frag = (function () {
            var boldText = "<span style='background-color: yellow; display: inline;'>" + searchText + "</span>";
            var html = currentNode.data.replace(regex, boldText);
            var wrap = document.createElement('div');
            frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            wrap.innerHTML = html;
            while (wrap.firstChild) {
                frag.appendChild(wrap.firstChild);
            }

            return frag;
        })();

        parent.insertBefore(frag, currentNode);
        parent.removeChild(currentNode);

    }

}
```

The problem with that function is that on the first click, it only finds the first occurrence of the word TEST in each Paragraph, and only if I click find again it will highlight the other TEST word.

I hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: you should use the global `g` modifier to look for every occurence aside from the case insensitive `i`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question you should add the flag g (for global) to the regex
something like

```
var regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'ig');
```

See also [here](http://www.2ality.com/2013/08/regexp-g.html) for reference

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex as shown below and try it:

```
var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ? new RegExp(searchText, 'gi') : searchText;
```